# Please tell me my data isn't gone... lie to me even

Tags: mysql, linux

In a moment of ignorance I setup my webserver to auto backup all data to another machine.

not a problem except I just mearly `cp -R /var/lib/mysql` so all I ended up getting was hundreds and hundreds of backups of `DB.opt` and `table.frm` files

From my understanding I didn't pull any data in these files. Is this true?

If so are these any good to me at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question, or even what you did, but let's walk this through.

If all you did was to issue a `cp -R /var/lib/mysql /path/to/backup`, then this does not harm your existing data.

It is also an incorrect backup method. Your backup itself is probably useless (unless all tables are MyISAM and you issued a `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`).

What's further unclear is your description of `.opt` and `.frm` files. Is that all you got? That's strange, because you should have also got some `*.MYD` files, and some `*.ibd` files or an `ibdata1` file.

Which storage engines are you using for your tables? What is the output of

```
mysql> select @@datadir;
mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_data_file_path' ;
mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_data_home_dir' ;
```

?

Last, I don't understand from your question whether data has been deleted from your webserver (containing your MySQL data).